# Moving configuration from mod_wsgi to script for debugging

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I've inherited a Flask application run using mod_wsgi on an apache server.  It came with no debugging setup, so I whipped up a quick debugging script to run the app using the `werkzeug.run_simple()` method.  I'm having issues with porting two mod_wsgi options over to the script.

`WSGIPythonPath` seems like the simpler one.  I'm not quite sure how it works, but does this basically append the specified paths to PYTHONPATH environment variable?

`WSGIScriptAlias` is the more problematic one.  In the apache config it's pretty standard:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /path/to/myapp.wsgi
```

This turns `app.route('/login')` to `/myapp/login` in the URL.  How do I prefix all URLs with `/myapp` in the wsgi script in the same manner as `WSGIScriptAlias`?

Let me know if you need more info and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`WSGIPythonPath`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) does indeed append modules to the system path.  According to its docs it does the equivalent of running [`site.addsitedir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.addsitedir) for every entry (unless you are running mod_wsgi 1.x, in which case it did the equivalent of `sys.path.append`):

```
import site

for p in list_of_paths:
    site.addsitedir(p)
```

This adds each entry to `sys.path` *and* it also scans the directory for `.pth` files and adds the entries in any such files it finds to `sys.path` as well (which means eggs will work as expected).

For `WSGIScriptAlias` you can simply set the [configuration variable `APPLICATION_ROOT`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values) in the Flask app's `config`:

```
app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"] = "/myapp"
```

Comment: Even in mod_wsgi 1.X it more or less did the same thing. It did it by sys.path.append() though which means .pth files were not honoured.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton - you're absolutely right - I've updated the sentence to be clear.  Thank you!